# How to query for time not covered

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table 'sessions' like this:

```
id | start                    | end
1  | "2018-05-17 07:51:38.392"| "2018-05-17 08:51:38.392"
2  | "2018-05-17 09:51:38.392"| "2018-05-17 10:51:38.392"
3  | "2018-05-17 17:51:38.392"| "2018-05-17 18:51:38.392"
4  | "2018-05-18 07:51:38.392"| "2018-05-18 17:51:38.392"
```

now I want to query the (sum of) time within the actual *day* of the timestamps (day starts at min(start and ends at (max end) ) where the time is NOT covered by sessions.

so for 2018-05-17 the result would be

11 hours total - 3 hours covered = 8 hours idle

Comment: If it's only one day per session, I suppose you could just do something like 24hours-sum(end-start)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total` is the difference `max(end_t)- min(start_t)` and `covered` is the `sum(end_t - start_t)`:

```
with my_table(id, start_t, end_t) as (
values
    (1, '2018-05-17 07:51:38.392'::timestamp, '2018-05-17 08:51:38.392'::timestamp),
    (2, '2018-05-17 09:51:38.392', '2018-05-17 10:51:38.392'),
    (3, '2018-05-17 17:51:38.392', '2018-05-17 18:51:38.392'),
    (4, '2018-05-18 07:51:38.392', '2018-05-18 17:51:38.392')
)

select 
    start_t::date as day,
    max(end_t) - min(start_t) as total, 
    sum(end_t - start_t) as covered,
    max(end_t) - min(start_t) - sum(end_t - start_t) as idle
from my_table
group by 1
order by 1

    day     |  total   | covered  |   idle   
------------+----------+----------+----------
 2018-05-17 | 11:00:00 | 03:00:00 | 08:00:00
 2018-05-18 | 10:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 00:00:00
(2 rows)
```